# JavaScript callback function seems to work, but does not draw the data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I've already been through many tutorials on callbacks (e.g. [here](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/), [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/callback%20javascript?mode=all) and [this gem](https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks))
By far the best one was [this gem](https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks). Especially this part helped me to understand.

```
function addOne(thenRunThisFunction) {
  waitAMinuteAsync(function waitedAMinute() {
    thenRunThisFunction()
  })
}

addOne(function thisGetsRunAfterAddOneFinishes() {})
```

So I implemented it as described there. Now everything seems to work on console output, but it does not render my *d3 force directed graph* as expected.

```
[some fancy variables used by force graph]

function draw(json) {
    java.alert(json);
    [awsome force graph stuff]
};

var data = undefined;

function readInputStream(callback){
    data = java.getJSONObject();
    if(!data == ""){
        java.alert("success");
    } else {
        java.alert("failure");
    }
    callback();
}

function prepareDraw() {
    java.alert("prepare called");
    draw(data);
}

readInputStream(prepareDraw);
```

Please note that `java` is an identifier. I'm running it all in a JavaFX WebView and all methods after `java.` are actual java methods I use in JavaScript. See this:

```
public class JStoFXBridge {
    private String json;

    public String getJSONObject(){
        return json;
    }
    public void setJSONObject(String string){
        this.json = string;
    }
    public void alert(String alert){
        System.out.println("Alert: " + alert);
    }
}
```

Now my console prints:

```
Alert: success
Alert: prepare called
Alert: {"nodes":[{"name":"sepp","id":0,"group":2},{"name":"hans","id":1,"group":6}, [...]
```

Which is the right format for my JSON String and which is (as far as I see it) in the right order to be executet. `data` gets filled and is not empty. `the callback method` gets called. My `draw function` has a `filled & valid` JSON String. What is going wrong here? I have no explination why this won't work.

Comment: Your code looks fine, at least, the flow is what you expect (and you can see that from your output). Are you sure the problem isn't in the part of `draw()` that you left out?

Comment: If I was to copy the JSON String and asign it directly to `var data` and call `draw(data);` it would work, so I don't see the problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's easier than you think...

```
java.alert("prepare called");
var json = JSON.parse(data);
draw(json);
```

Problem: `data` was a String, d3 wants a JSON Object. [Watch here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622936/render-d3-graph-from-a-string-of-json-instead-of-a-json-file). New output:

```
Alert: success
Alert: prepare called
Alert: [object Object]
```

Now renders the graph just fine. `var data = {"nodes":[{"name":"sepp", [...]` works because JavaScript interpretes it as a JSON Object.